# Struggling with strtotime, getting expect parameter 2 to be long error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script that will calculate dates into a database depending on the value entered for `cdr_original_install_date`.

If if is blank I would like it to enter NULL for both `$cdr_install` and `$cdr_renew`.

If not I would like `$cdr_install` to be the date entered in `cdr_original_install_date`, `$cdr_renew` to be the same date plus one year.  If the `$cdr_renew` date has not passed I would like it to change the value of $cdr_support to 'Initial Warranty';

I have tried several ways to write this but the only bit that works is if no date is entered NULL is saved to the database.  If I enter a date I either get dates entered as 1970-01-01 or an error saying that `strtotime()` expects parameter 2 to be long, string given which refers to the line adding one year to `$cdr_install`.

```
if($_POST['cdr_original_install_date'] == ''){
    $cdr_install = 'NULL';
    $cdr_renew = 'NULL';
} else {
    $cdr_install = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['cdr_original_install_date']));
    $cdr_renew = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cdr_install,'+ 1 year'));
        if(strtotime($cdr_renew) > time()){
            $cdr_support = 'Initial Waranty';
        }
}
```

The database field are just date so the problem doesn't appear to be the formatting of the date value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation of `strtotime()`: http://php.net/strtotime

It states that:

> time [-> the first parameter]
>
> A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in Date and Time Formats.
>
> now [-> the second parameter]
>
> The timestamp which is used as a base for the calculation of relative dates.

So, only the first parameter is a time expression in string form. The second parameter is the date you start from. (`+ 1 year` from the unix timestamp `strtotime($_POST['cdr_original_install_date'])` on)

So use:

```
strtotime('+ 1 year', strtotime($_POST['cdr_original_install_date']));
```

Comment: Hi @bwoebi: I am facing the same issue. At all the places I am using strtotime() with first parameter only but still it throws parameter 2 error. Strange thing is on Staging and Local environment it's fine but on Production server we are facing this issue. PHP version difference can create problem?

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp as far as I could see in the changelog, there's nothing which should have changed in that regard… There's something fishy, I guess… But really, why do you have different environments on staging and production?

Answer (score 2):

it should be `.` not `,`

```
$cdr_renew = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cdr_install.'+ 1 year'));
```

Comment: This works too it seems; the examples in the docs were not suggesting that this works...

Comment: I have read the documentation and the comma will work as well as the full stop, but thanks for you answer